# Проблема с вложенными маршрутами django

Tags: python, django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема. У автора все работает, а у меня ничего не загружается. Если не создавать `news/urls`, а просто все маршруты описать в `cumar/urls` проблем нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема?

Вот ролик https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xt2WTZS028E&list=PLmC7X4gkQWCeyIdLxHZdts-3tkcrxP4-o&index=6&t=511s

Comment: Из видимых различий на втором скрине у автора в 6-й строке обработчик index указан без скобок. Что логично, так как в path нужно передавать его как аргумент, не вызывая.

Comment: Без скобок тоже не работает

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего дело в разных версиях django в 4.0 правильно вот так.
Вот ссылка на доки
https://django.fun/docs/django/ru/4.0/intro/tutorial01/

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('news/', include('news.urls')),
]



from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('test/', views.test, name='test'),
]
```